# NestJS doesn't start within apps

Tags: nestjs, turborepo

I recently started using turborepo.
I added a new app into `/apps` directory, called `api` by doing the following

```sh
$ cd apps
$ nest new api
```

Now if I try and run nest api

```sh
$ cd api
$ yarn start:dev
```

It fails with following error,

```
../../node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3100:14 - error         type LibraryManagedAttributes<C, P>dAttributes'.
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
3100
  ../../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3100:14
    3100         type LibraryManagedAttributes<C, P> = C extends React.MemoExoticComponent<infer T> | React.LazyExoticComponent<infer T>
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'LibraryManagedAttributes' was also declared here.

../../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3100:14 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'LibraryManagedAttributes'.

3100         type LibraryManagedAttributes<C, P> = C extends React.MemoExoticComponent<infer T> | React.LazyExoticComponent<infer T>
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  ../../node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3100:14
    3100         type LibraryManagedAttributes<C, P> = C extends React.MemoExoticComponent<infer T> | React.LazyExoticComponent<infer T>
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'LibraryManagedAttributes' was also declared here.

[4:35:02 PM] Found 2 errors. Watching for file changes.
```

Help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it to work after changing the tsconfig.json in `apps/api`

```
{
  "extends": "tsconfig/base.json",
  "include": [
    "./**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share that repo structure ?

Comment: @OrenM https://ibb.co/wM1dPCg